Driving a 48 V motor with a 20 V lithium-ion battery
What is the best approach to drive a higher voltage motor from lower voltage lithium-ion batteries?
The premise is that I want to try making a cordless drill using a commercial 20 V battery but with a 48 V motor.
First I thought of using a DC-DC boost, but for a 600 W to 800 W motor it just isn't feasible because this is a handheld device we are talking about, also price wise it simply was out of budget for almost 20 A output.
Now… for the power source, I found some pretty interesting 21700 Samsung 5000 mAh lithium-ion batteries with peak current of 45 A  for about 10$ a piece, also sold as power drills battery packs for 80$ for 8000 mAh 20 V (I don't know if i am allowed to post links, but search for Parkside PAPS 208 A1)... so this would fit my power criteria but not voltage.
So I thought to use a charge pump of sorts... excuse my awful drawing.

How this will play out is:

both the NC switches are closed and the NO is open

both the motor and capacitor have 20 V applied

the capacitor charges and the motor is being driver from the battery alone, so 20 V



When the capacitor is full, I switch all 3 switches, so the motor is now powered by 20 V battery and 20 V capacitor, so 40 V total.

since the capacitor charges fast (and also discharges) this has to happen with a high enough frequency to keep the median voltage as close as possible to 40 V



Now, for the capacitor, i thought anything higher than 0.1 F should do and here's the math
0.1 F at 20 V is 20 J (0.1 * 20 * 20 / 2), and 20 J is 20 W-s,
if we take into consideration a 100 ms discharge it should be 200 W for 100 ms (and this is purely theoretic because I don't know how fast will this capacitor discharge, it just means that with a 100 ms boost time this would have added a maximum of 200 W to the total power output, put 2 together and the output power is doubled)
Before I ramble too much, can someone explain to me if this approach is possible or am I just mistaken?
I know the ripple will be enormous and the motor noise will be horrible.
Also, the maximum output power will be for about 100 ms.
Lastly, I thought also about the DC-DC voltage doubler you can find on Instructables.com, but I don't think this will reach the power requirements.
Lastly... I also could use a brushless motor, and while 1 phase is being energized, the remaining 2 have their capacitors charging.

Welcome! Please start sentences with capital letter and end with period. A charge pump is a DC-DC converter, but not a suitable one at 600 W. Your opinions would be 1. Battery voltage to suit your motor directly. 2. Motor voltage to suit your battery directly. 3. A 600+ W boost converter. Option 3 will be costly, which is why you won’t find it in battery operated tools and machines.

A charge pump is way worse for this than a standard boost converter with inductors. Have you considered re-winding the motor? It'd probably be easier.

To reply to Winny: A suitable battery would have 12 cells to get to the desired voltage, costly and bulky, a different motor isn't in question because this would be some sort of conversion from wired to battery powered, but the motor stays the same, also a DC DC boost wont fit in a power drill housing. And to reply to Hearth: I don't need the motor to actually run off of 48V, I am more than happy to let it run off 20V and just give it the last push only when the bolt is tightened to get it up to required torque which is not available on 20V

I'm writing another comment because of the character limit of the previous one. I also thought to use the 20V battery to run the motor till the screw is tightened enough that the motor cannot drive it in anymore, and while it's doing that (or while it's idle) charge 2x 0.1F 60V capacitors trough a small DC boost, And when the motor cannot drive the screw anymore with 20V because it lacks torque, it gives the last push using only the capacitors -no pump- (0.2 x 60 x 60 /2 = 360J or 3600W for 100ms) and if it doesn't reach the desired torque, it signals that it's recharging and just tries again.

How about using 2 batteries instead of a single one? A lot of power tools do exactly this when pressed for both battery compatibility and the power level required.

Then you are out of options. Also, last push = boost, so no help there.

To reply to fraxinus: 2 batteries will get bulky, one is already bulky enough, also it can store some serious Wh which I don't need since this is for a battery driven screwdriver which basically freely spins the bolt for 90% of the cycle and gives the full motor power for less than a second (the torque is electronically limited do the desired level). And to reply to Winny: I meant -no boost- as in no charge pump involved, the motor is spun by the charge of the capacitors only, charged at 60V by a small 60V 1A DC boost, should take about 6 seconds to fully charge 0.2F

@Damir, The voltage across a capacitor drops as it's discharged. They cannot discharge abruptly because of motor inductance and inertia. You'd get an initial "kick" from 60 VDC, and a longer tail of far less toque. Use two batteries; 40 V should be close enough, and you'd get twice the run time.
